# Proving pointwise convergence of a sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In some example tasks for infinite function series I'm learning from pointwise convergence is proven like we are dealing with sequence instead of series - $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ when , result being limiting function of a given series.

So, for example if following series is given:

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^{n^{2}x}}
$$

Pointwise convergence is proven by:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{e^{n^{2}x}} = 0$$

I'm not sure if that is correct, anyone could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Convergence of the n-th term of $\sum a_n$ to $0$ does not guarantee convergence of the series. The given series is not convergent if $x<0$. For $x=0$ it is obviously convergent. For $x>0$ apply ratio test to prove that it is convergent.  [ $\lim \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}=\lim e^{-2nx} e^{-x} =0 <1$ so the series is convergent.

Comment: Can we apply a ratio test to the function series?

Comment: Sure, for pointwise convergence all tests for series of constants are available even when the terms are functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a series to converge, convergence of the sequence to zero is an obvious necessary condition. But it is not sufficient: if the terms decrease slowly, the sum can be unbounded.

Consider the sequence

$$1,\frac12,\frac12,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\cdots$$

Obviously it tends to zero, but the partial sums diverge.

---

To study convergence of a series, squeezing remains the basic technique and comparison to a geometric series leads to the ratio test.

Another important result is that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha}$$ converges iff $\alpha>1$.

Comment: I don't think that the question asks to conclude about the given example.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of the difference but example solutions I have access to do just that, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @MateuszSzwed: well, what are you asking then ?

Comment: Whether proving a pointwise convergence of a series by limit of a term is correct.

Comment: @MateuszSzwed: ok.

Answer (score 0):

For a sequence of functions $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$, pointwise convergence means that for every fixed $x$ the sequence of values $(f_k(x))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges.

In your case
$$
f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{x}{e^{n^{2}x}}
$$
and pointwise convergence means that for all fixed $x$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x}{e^{n^{2}x}}$ converges.